# Filtering dataframe rows based on count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like

```
Fruit   Month
----------------
A   Jan
A   Feb
A   Mar 
B   Sep
```

I want to filter the table in such a way that I get only top n rows say two for each fruit Example

```
Fruit   Month
----------------
A   Jan
A   Feb 
B   Sep
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `groupby()` and `head()`:

```
df.groupby('Fruit').head(2)
```

Outputs:

```
  Fruit Month
0     A   Jan
1     A   Feb
3     B   Sep
```

Comment: ahh i think i got this question wrong. Guessed its based on months

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't entirely sure what the OP was aiming for, but this seems to be the most simplistic way to achieve their desired output.

Comment: This works like a charm but the issue I have is it does not maintain the initial order of top two but selects random two. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: It will not select a random two, can you please include a revised example in your original post with what you are observing?